# Regex question in C#

Tags: c#, regex

how to remove only one char (") if there two("") from the string in C# (Regex )

ex.:

```
123"43""343"54"" ==>  123"43"343"54"

"abc""def"gh""i  ==>  "abc"def"gh"i
```

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`someString.Replace(@"""""",@"""");` should work, shouldn't it?

```
while (someString.IndexOf(@"""""") > -1)
{
   someString = someString.Replace(@"""""",@"""");
}
```

Comment: cool !!, thank's !
and how i can remove " from the begin and the end of a string ?

Comment: You don't need the while loop.  String.Replace with replace all instances.

Comment: @juharr, this is coding for the scenario where there are instances of 2 *or more* quotes in a row.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need regex for this. Just search for the sub-string `""` and replace it with `"`

Comment: See http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Regular_Expression_Recipes%E2%80%94Replacing_Characters_or_Words_in_a_String for examples

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex regExp = new Regex("\"\"");
string test = "123\"\"123\"\"123";
string tempTxt = regExp.Replace(test, "\"");
```

Something like this?
But yeah, i think Regex isn't good choise here.